# Add JSON object to Dictionary Value

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm currently trying to do a function that will get a key(string)/value(JSON) pair from a dictionary stored at a database and add information about the player into a temporary JSON(playersInfo), then set that JSON object back to the value which i got earlier, i'm still very noob at javascript and i couldn't find the right syntax to do it.

If there's anything i can do to make myself clear please let me know.

Both Get...Data() functions return different dictionaries.

```
handlers.UpdateJackpotPlayers = function(args, context) {
  var playersInfo = {};
  var userData = server.GetUserData({
    PlayFabId: currentPlayerId
  });
  var serverData = server.GetTitleInternalData();

  playersInfo = JSON.parse(serverData.Data["jackpotPlayers"].Value);
  playersInfo.PlayerId += JSON.parse(" / " + currentPlayerId);

  playersInfo.PlayerName += JSON.parse(" / " +
    userData.Data["PlayerName"].Value);
  playersInfo.AchievedJackpot += JSON.parse(" / " + args);

  server.SetTitleInternalData({
    "Key": "jackpotPlayers",
    "Value": JSON.stringify(playersInfo)
  });
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: JSON.parse(" / " is invalid, it will always throw an error. JSON.parse expects a valid JSON string. Valid JSON does not start with / so that's one issue with your code. There is no need to parse an object that was already parsed. Just use userData.Data["PlayerName"].

Comment: So much JSON where it isn't. [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: the final visual result i want is something like:

    {
        PlayersId: "ID1 / ID2 / ID3",
        PlayersName: "Name1 / Name2 / Name3"
        AchievedJackpot: "false / false / true"
    }

does JSON store multiple values do a single key automatically like a C#/C++ multimap?

Comment: @willianbrasilmetzger JSON can store whatever you like however you like, if you want / seperated strings then you go right ahead, if you want it to be an array then all you need to do is make it an array. I feel like you are not very familiar with exactly what a JSON object is so try reading up on it here: https://www.json.org/ If you still have questions after that please feel free to ask them.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". Either it's an object - then it's a Javascript object - or it's JSON - then it's a string (that is formatted following certain conventions which together define the JSON format).

Comment: thanks a lot @AdamH this link was really helpfull.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i wasn't aware of those differences.